# How to add token in bloomrpc

Tags: grpc, proto

I am using bloomrpc for testing grpc requests and responses. I don't know how to add token to my request.

How can I add `token` to my `grpc` request in `bloomrpc`?

Answer (score 7):

it is easy:

```
{
    "Authorization": "your token here"
}
```

[image]

Comment: For Bearer JWT Tokens e.g. { "Authorization": "Bearer xaz012ABC" }